# ¿Como crear un escalado de un windows form C#? Sin usar anchor ni dock

Tags: c#, windows-forms

tengo la necesidad de crear un escalado en una aplicación windows form la cual se debería ajustar: el formulario,los controles y la letra a cualquier resolución de pantalla y sin usar ni dock ni anchor.Y no logro ajustar. Agradecería mucho su colaboración.

Comment: Bienvenido Luis, para que podamos entender mejor la pregunta, editala y agrega el codigo

Comment: ¿Y cómo esperas que se ajusten los componentes? ¿Con _majia_? _(Sí, con 'J')_.

Comment: El punto es que he investigado, probado y desarrollado distintos códigos para tratar de que el mismo windows form se ajuste a las diferentes resoluciones, pero no logro el prometido.Por ello plateaba la pregunta a este foro a ver si alguien a podido resolverlo esta pregunta.

Comment: Esas propiedades que mencionan son las que hacen que un formulario pueda cambiar de tamaño sin dañar la visualización, y si pruebas `Panel`?

Comment: He usado Sizef,float, AutoScale... pero no logro la perfección de ajuste de los mismos en todas las resoluciones. Y me gustaria saber si alquien a logrado resolver esta incógnita o siempre lo han manejado con dock y  anchor

Comment: He trabajado con el float layout panel ...pero no me gustan por que ancla los controles a un laterar. Y el punto es ajustarlo a la pantalla y no que se anclen a un laterar es como trabajar con un wfp

Comment: Se puede. Debe ser una cantidad de codigo bastante importante. Haz un [mcve] y capaz podemos fijarnos donde falla. E igual, no le veo el sentido a hacer algo q se hace solo. E igual, pensar que en wpf esta todo anclado tambien es un error. Y si esto es un proyecto escolar o solamente una duda teorica, que mejor que mostrarnos hasta donde llegaste

Comment: Y de paso, mira [ask] y [tour]

Comment: La mejor solucion es usar un `TableLayoutPanel`

Comment: Bueno era una duda que me comía hace tiempo, por que estar trabajado con los dock y anchor es muy tedioso, aunque no le quito el merito que sean funcionales, pero bueno ya logro mi prometido el código no es muy grande y solo instancio la clase, llamo los métodos y listo , el código reestructura los controles independientemente del tipo de control,o resolución y facilita mucho los procesos de creación.

Comment: TableLayoutPanel a mi parecer no era la mejor forma vendría ser lo mismo que anclar los controles  y no se ajustarían a diferentes resoluciones. Aunque si tu lo lograste así fantástico, eso es lo que me fascina de la programación independientemente de como lo programe uno ay casi infinitas formas de llegar al resultado propuesto

Comment: @Luis Chavarria te equivocas, TableLayoutPanel, dependiendo de lo que necesitas, puede ser la mejor forma. Tienes que saber usarlo. El tablelayoutpanel se ajusta si manejas porcentajes para ancho de columnas y algo de renglones.

Comment: Al contrario. La solución que le di fue la mas conveniente a mi parecer. Ya me permite usar todo los controles por defecto en el visual studio. colocarlos en cualquier lugar y se que se escalaran sin deformarse. Le mostraría un vídeo de lo que hace para que  se diera una mejor idea de las capacidades del código, nos tante desconozco como compartir vídeos aquí, si es que se pueden o no .